# Orthonormal basis of a infinite dimensional Hilbert subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable, infinite dimensional, complex Hilbert space.

Let $BH$ be a orthonormal basis of $H$.

Let $V$ be a Hilbert subspace of $H$.

Is it true that exists a subset $BV \subset BH$ such that $BV$ is orthonormal basis of $V$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider $H = \mathbb C^2$ with basis $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ and $V = \mathrm{span} \{(1,1)\}$.
Of course this example extends to the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: ok @André S. thanks